# Bxslider broken after switching pages

Tags: javascript, bxslider

Im trying to add a slider to my meteor.js project.

I'm currently using Bxslider and I want to show the slider only when im in a specific route, it works perfectly when it loads the first time but when I add the conditional statements of zimme:active-route:

```
{{#if isActivePath '/'}}

{{/if}}
```

The slider shows images stacked one on top of each other.

This its the code:

Template code:

```
{{#if isActivePath '/'}}
        <div class="col-md-3 slider" >
            <ul class="bxslider">
                <li><img class="img-responsive" src="/assets/tds/img/15.jpg" /></li>
                <li><img class="img-responsive" src="/assets/tds/img/16.jpg" /></li>
                <li><img class="img-responsive" src="/assets/tds/img/17.jpg" /></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
{{/if}}
```

slider.js:

```
Template.header.rendered = function() {
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    auto: true,
    autoControls: true,
    adaptiveHeight: true,
    responsive: true,
    infiniteLoop: true,
    pager: true,
    mode: 'fade'
});
```

};

I think the problem is: When I switch pages, the condition "if" overwrite the current slider div, but I don't know how to fix it, any suggestions?

Slider when the page first loads:

http://gyazo.com/f6679142a48fcab9cda0b5e938ab65c2

After switching pages:

http://gyazo.com/1da3271ebc6be6434d73ffbe36d5cd4c

Comment: To get a better chance to get an answer, could you post the image of what you get ? If you don't have enough rep to do that, then post it on imgur and edit the question with the link.